# Python Dictionary should return a value rather than None

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a csv file which consists

`a,b
2,3
4,5
4,7
4,7`

(where a,b is a column values)
Below i have two functions where the first function will read the csv and  assign 'a' as key and 'b' as value in a dictionary

Second function i will pass 'a' value as an argument and it returns b as a value when i use that function.If there is no value for 'a' i get None.

```
def x (id):
    dict1= {}
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf') as f:
        for i in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace= True)
        dict1[i['a']] = row['b']
    print('im happy now' )



def getx (a):
    return dict1.get(a, None)
```

It works perfectly.

Now I have a csv file with four column values

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,r,4
2,g,4,6
3,d,4,6
```

For this i have written a code like

```
def x ():
    dict1= {}
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf') as f:
        for i in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace= True)
        dict1[i['a']] = dict(dict1[i['b']] = dict(dict1[i['c']] = row['d']))
    print('im happy now' )



def getx (a):
    return dict1.get(dict1['a']['b']['c'], None)
```

My logic is to show

```
dict1[i['a']] = dict(dict1[i['b']] = dict(dict1[i['c']] = row['d']))
```

as

```
dict1 :{
   'a':{
       'b':{
           'c':2,
           'c':4,
           'c':4
       }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if what i have written above is right.

I need to return 'd' as a value when i pass dict1[a[]b][c]. It returns me empty value.

Expected value is for the combination of a,b,c i need a value as d.

For eg: from the above csv.. For the combination of  1,2,r i need to return 4 as an output

Update:

I realized that the column 'a' has duplicate values and it cant be handled in dictionary keys which skips the duplicate key record.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_1 = defaultdict(list)

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for r in f.readline():
        i= r['a']
        j= r['b']
        k= r['c']
        l =r['d']
        details = [j,k,l]
        dict_1[i].append((details))
        print(dict_1)
```

which gives me

```
{'1' :[('k', '3', '5'),('e','3','2')], '4' :[('r','3','2'),('e','2','1')],....................}
```

If i have dict_1 in my first function as above.
Now, any suggestions like how can i get the value of 'd' by passing a,b,c as an argument in my second function, else NONE?

Comment: A dictionary can't have multi values against a single key. Try storing those values in a list instead (against the key)

Comment: For a,b, c columns I need d column as a value. So If in list how can I manage all in one..

Comment: I chose dictionary so that for a,b,c combination I can get d value.... If in list I'm not sure how can we achieve. @rdas

Comment: The example you have show above is not possible. But you can't store it like this: `'c': [2, 4, 4]`

Comment: @rdas . I see there are duplicates in my 'a' column and as a dictionary it doesnt accept duplicate key value. I miss many records in it. Can we achieve it with List?

Comment: @rdas I have updated my question with new approach and made key as unique with values as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the csv module for that. Also, you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, you'd only overwrite previously set values.

```
def x():
    dict1= {}
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf') as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            a, b, c, d = i.split(',')
            dict1[a] = {b: {c: d}}

def getx(a, b, c):
    try:
        return dict1[a][b][c]
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: Appreciate your Answer but I see there are duplicates in my 'a' column and as dictionary doesnt accept duplicate key value. I miss many records in it. Is there any other approach where we can achieve if we have duplicates in 'a' column

Comment: You can have multiple 'a' values, as long as you don't have the same a,b,c tuple. For a table like `a,b,c,d
1,2,r,4
1,g,4,6`, you'd have a dictionary like {1: {2:{'r':4}, 'g': {4:6}}}. 
If you have the same a,b,c tuple more than once, you can add those values to a list: `dict1[a][b][c].append(d)`. Of course you'd have to initialize this list before appending to it.